# Launch Adobe reader from Pantheon?

Tags: app-shortcuts, default

I can launch pdf's in Adobe Acrobat Reader from Nautilus (Files) with a single click having set the default application in Pantheon.  However in Pantheon itself I get an error "Could not open files or URLs with this app".

Acrobat launches normally otherwise including from the Firefox downloads drop down menu.

Any way to fix this as a symbolic link?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What it cames to my mind is to navigate with pantheon-files to a pdf file you want to open, right click on it, choose Open With and select **Choose another application** in the bottom of the list **no matter that your favorite application is above**.

This way you will launch a popup window with a list of the recommended for this file type applications. Choose the one you want and set On the checkbox below **Set as default**.  If your application is not in the recommended applications list, choose **View All Applications** in order the list to be extended.

This is the easiest way to set a default application for a file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, done that.  Doesn't work in Pantheon, works perfectly in Nautilus though.  I'm thinking that Pantheon can't open 32bit apps?